# SonicWALL TZ300 Setup

Tags: firewall, subnet, network, sonicwall

I'm just about to start setting up a SonicWALL TZ300 on my network, I'm trying to get my head around how the network should be set up (this is my first time installing a SonicWALL device) and looking for some help/direction. I am using a Draytek Vigor2826.

I plan on plugging the LAN port on the TZ into my network switch and the WAN port into LAN1 on the router. The LAN and WAN ports of the TZ will be on different subnets as I believe the appliance will not allow both to be on the same subnet, please correct me if I am wrong on this.

**Planned IP config**

```
Router LAN IP:      192.168.1.1

TZ LAN IP:          192.168.0.1

TZ WAN IP:          192.168.1.2
TZ Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1 (same as router)
TZ DNS1:            192.168.1.1 (same as router)

PC IP:              192.168.0.x
PC Gateway:         192.168.0.1 (same as TZ)
```

This planned setup should route the PC's gateway to the LAN port on the TZ, the TZ WAN gateway will be set up to the LAN port of the router, hopefully routing internet traffic to the PC's.

Any advice on this planned setup would be appreciated. I'm unsure whether or not this is the correct or incorrect way to set this up, or if I would be better off setting up the TZ300 WAN and LAN ports on the same subnet to simplify things if possible?

Thanks

[image: network setup]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Comment: This isn't for home networking.

Comment: You are using a home networking router, and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: The reason you're having trouble wrapping your head around it is because, as Ron said, you have two routers. You either need to ditch the SonicWALL and use the Draytek as your router, or replace the Draytek with an ADSL modem (or put the Draytek into Bridge Mode) so the SonicWALL receives the WAN IP from your ISP. Trying to have a router-behind-router is just going to make your life needlessly difficult. Why do you even have the SonicWALL?

Comment: No problem, everything set up and working now. The SonicWALL is being used for remote access.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you suggest in your comment, this is not for a personal network, then you should really get rid of the consumer-grade router. Your SonicWALL is capable of being the WAN router for your network.

If you insist on keeping the router, then you should not run NAT on the SonicWALL because double NAT can cause you problems. You will also need to let the consumer-grade router know about the network(s) on the other side of the SonicWALL. I'm not sure if the consumer-grade router, which is explicitly off-topic here, can do that. Routers learn about routes in three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Through dynamic routing protocols

Since the network on the other side of the SonicWALL is not directly connected to the router, you will need to use either method 2 or 3 so that the router knows about any network on the other side of the SonicWALL.